# Compute $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(1-z^n)(1-z^{n+1})}z^{n-1}$ and show its uniform convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, analysis, power-series

Given the power series $$P:=\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(1-z^n)(1-z^{n+1})}z^{n-1}$$ I want to show that $P$ converges uniformly in $\mathbb{C}$ and compute its limit.

I've tried to multiply $P$ with $(1-z)z$ which yields $$\tilde{P}=\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{z^{n+1}-1}+\frac{1}{z^n-1}\right)$$ However, I'm unable to continue from here. What's the trick now?

Comment: I believe that this only converges uniformly on compact subsets of $|z|\lt1$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Note that
$$
\frac{z^{n-1}}{(1-z^n)(1-z^{n+1})}
=\frac1{1-z}\left(\frac{z^{n-1}}{1-z^n}-\frac{z^n}{1-z^{n+1}}\right)
$$
Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{z^{n-1}}{(1-z^n)(1-z^{n+1})}
&=\frac1{1-z}\left(\frac1{1-z}-\frac{z^N}{1-z^{N+1}}\right)\\
&=1-\frac1{1-z}\frac{z^N}{1-z^{N+1}}
\end{align}
$$
You should be able to use this on compact subsets of $|z|\lt1$.

Comment: Since $$\displaystyle\frac{z^N}{1-z^{N+1}}\to 0\;\;\;(N\to\infty)$$ There series converges against $1$. Now, if $|z|11$ and $\varepsilon >0$ we've got $$\left|\left(1-\frac{1}{1-z}\frac{z^N}{1-z^{N+1}}\right)-1\right|=\frac{1}{|1-z|}\frac{|z|^N}{|1-z^{N+1}|}\le \frac{1}{1-|z|}\frac{|z|^N}{1-|z|^{N+1}}\le |z|^N$$ Where do we need the restriction to compact subsets?

Comment: The inequality $$\frac1{1-|z|}\frac{|z|^N}{1-|z|^{N+1}}\le|z|^N$$ is not correct. Even if it were, this still doesn't show uniform convergence out to $|z|=1$.

Comment: @robojohn - It should be correct since $1-|z|\in (0,1)$ and $1-|z|^{N+1}\in (0,1)$.

Comment: You cannot find a uniform $N$ for all $|z|\lt1$. For example, can you find an $N$ so that $|z|^N\le0.001$ for all $|z|\lt1$? Refer to [uniform convergence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_convergence).